# How to be alerted of razor view errors

Tags: razor, .net-core

My dotnet core projects build and deploy with no errors, but I could have a honking game breaking exception in a cshtml view that doesn't get picked up at all.  In an ideal world I'd have tests checking every crud page, but not on this project, client doesn't have the budget.  There's too many views to open them all and check as well (every time)

Is there any way to have the build fail if there's any bad code in the cshtml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the default in ASP.NET Core 2.1 since views will be always compiled on build and only dynamically re-compiled on edits.

In the meanwhile, you can add this to your csproj file (built this originally on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/71#issuecomment-282494937)):

```
<Target Name="SetMvcRazorOutputPath">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MvcRazorOutputPath>$(IntermediateOutputPath)</MvcRazorOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="_MvcRazorPrecompileOnBuild"
        DependsOnTargets="SetMvcRazorOutputPath;MvcRazorPrecompile"
        AfterTargets="Build" 
        Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' " />

 <Target Name="IncludePrecompiledViewsInPublishOutput"
        DependsOnTargets="_MvcRazorPrecompileOnBuild"
        BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish"
        Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_PrecompiledViewsOutput Include="$(MvcRazorOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).PrecompiledViews.dll" />
    <_PrecompiledViewsOutput Include="$(MvcRazorOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).PrecompiledViews.pdb" />
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(_PrecompiledViewsOutput->'%(FullPath)')"
        RelativePath="%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Identity)" 
        TargetPath="%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Filename)%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Extension)" 
        CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```